# GNU AWK Print Text Between Two Patterns Do Not Include Patterns

Tags: awk, gnu, matching, gsub

GNU AWK 5.1.1

I have an AWK expression below that I use to print the content between two patterns found in a .txt document but I'm not particularly happy with the expression, would like something more elegant any suggestions? I don't was SED just AWK.

I want to grab all the text between these tags but not including the tags.

```
<monDescription> and <endMonDescription>
```

If I simple use:

```
awk '/<monDescription>/,/<endMonDescription>/' ~mydocument.txt
```

It includes the `<monDescription>` and `<endMonDescription>` which I don't want.
So to fix this I pipe the AWK output to another AWK command using gsub:

```
awk '/<monDescription>/,/<endMonDescription>/' ~mydocument.txt | awk '{gsub(/<monDescription>|<endMonDescription>|DAVE:/, "")}1' | awk '{$1=$1;print}'
```

Then I also gsub "DAVE: " which is text content that occurs before and on the same line and the `<monDescription>` that I don't want. It's tough just to get clean text in-between patterns not before or after the patterns and not including the patterns themselves without slopping looking piping. Suggestions?

Here's a sample of input text:

```
DAVE:   <monDescription>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo,
rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis
eu pede mollis pretium.<endMonDescription>
```

Expected output should be:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean
> commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus
> et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam
> felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla
> consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet
> nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a,
> venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.

Comment: please update the question to include sample data that a) includes the `DAVE:` string, b) lines that do not have a match, and c) the expected output (corresponding to the new sample input); also, could the contents between the patterns include linefeeds? you've stated `sed` cannot be used ... can a html/xml tool be used or are these also not allowed?

Comment: also, can the input include multiple sets of matching patterns?

Comment: @KamilCuk, awk can do that: `seq 10 | awk '/4/,/7/'`

Comment: Please show a sample of the input text.

Comment: now update the question to show the expected output (corresponding to the sample input)

Comment: HTML/xml tool can't be used. I'm converting from word documents to text documents using libreoffice so I'm essentially trying to grab the text in-between tags.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. Mark, I would prefer not to use sed but I would invite maybe an alternative CLI tool that provide a cleaner code for what I'm trying to do. But I suppose that's another question / topic.  HTML/xml definitely cannot be used, I'm getting data directly from a Word .docx file that's being converted to a standard .txt file using Libreoffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
DAVE:   <monDescription>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo,
rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis
eu pede mollis pretium.<endMonDescription>
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="<[^>]*onDescription>"}NR%2==0' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo,
rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis
eu pede mollis pretium.
```

Explanation: I prepared regular expression which would match both `<monDescription>` and `<endMonDescription>` (you might elect to use both of these joined by `|` if regular expression which I provide will give false positives with your file), then I inform GNU `AWK` to use it as row separator (`RS`) and to `print` only even lines. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes that all starting tag has ending tag, there is not never nesting and every ending tag has starting tag somewhere before it.

(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)

Comment: I'll have to test this more thoroughly but this is by far the most elegant solution that works thus far. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

If there's leading or trailing, well, anything, try this non-proprietary-`awk` solution :

**INPUT (encapsulated, including trailing spaces)**

```
<<<<{DAVE:   <monDescription>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo,
rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis
eu pede mollis pretium.<endMonDescription>      }>>>>
```

**CODE**

```
# This also trims out final \n :
#      remove ORS= part to 
#      retain trailing newline

{m,n,g}awk ++NF OFS= RS='^$'  \
                ORS= FS='(^[^><]*)?[<](end)?[Mm]onDescription[>]([^><]*$)?'
```

**OUTPUT (encapsulated)**

```
<<<<{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum
sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo,
fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo,
rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis
eu pede mollis pretium.}>>>>
```